# Tinytex and TeXstudio (Mac)

Tags: texlive, texstudio, mac, distributions, tinytex

**How can I connect the LaTex distribution that I installed with Tinytex with TeXstudio?**

I have downloaded Tinytex from Rstudio (following the instructions [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/install-latex.html)).

From Rstudio I am now able to compile .tex files and obtain the expected pdf.

After that, I downloaded [TeXstudio](https://www.texstudio.org/) and try to compile the same .tex file on the same MacBook pro and TeXstudio do not find the latex distribution.
More precisely, when opening TeXstudio I obtain the following error:

> No LaTeX distribution was found on your system. As a result, the corresponding commands are not configured. This means, that you cannot compile your documents to the desired output format (e.g. pdf).
> A popular LaTeX distribution on OSX is MacTeX.
> If you intend to work with LaTeX, you'll most certainly want to install it.

**Remarks**:

I am using a MacBook Pro 14 inch, 2023 with macOS Ventura

I installed tinytex from R version 4.3.0 on may 2023 following the instructions [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/install-latex.html)

I am using TeXstudio version 4.5.2

Comment: Note that most LaTeX editors for Mac expects you to use MacTeX (arguably the easiest latex installation to install) which sets up a path component in a special way. You instead have to tell your editor exactly where the tinytex binaries are. Good luck

Comment: Untested, but try using `~/Library/TinyTeX/bin/x86_64-darwin` to replace the default `/usr/texbin/` in all the commands that use that path. Don't change any of the `/usr/local/bin` commands. Note also that TinyTeX hasn't installed many of those tools. TinyTeX isn't really designed to be used outside of R, so if you want a small Mac TeX distribution, consider installing [BasicTeX](https://www.tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html) instead.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks for the help. If the paths are the ones in `TeXstudio > Preferences > Commands` they are all empty and I do not have any path to modify. I was trying to find a way to specify the TeX distribution installed in R via TinyTex (where I am also installing additional packages and tools via R).

Comment: @Jim Right, so e.g. for each engine (pdflatex, lualatex, xelatex, latex) use `~/Library/TinyTeX/bin/x86_64-darwin/pdflatex` etc. as the command in the TeXStudio preferences. Perhaps before using this, check to see what directories are in `~/Library/TinyTeX/bin` and if there's one for the Apple silicon chips use that instead, but the basic idea is the same.  So the preference line for `pdflatex` should read `"~/Library/TinyTeX/bin/x86_64-darwin/pdflatex"  -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` or the relevant directory in `bin` if there's also an Apple silicon directory.

Comment: Thanks, @AlanMunn. I did what you suggested and it works now. The precise path in my case is `~Library/TinyTeX/bin/universal-darwin/pdflatex`. If you want to write an answer with your comment I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TinyTeX on a Mac installs its TeX binaries into `~/Library/TinyTeX/bin/universal-darwin`, according to your investigation based on my comments so you need to update the TeXStudio preferences to reflect that path for each engine, and other tools that are expected to be in the TeX `bin` directory.

So for each of the TeX engines, (`latex`, `pdflatex`, `lualatex`, and `xelatex` you need to add the following in the Commands section of the Preferences.

```
"~/Library/TinyTeX/bin/universal-darwin/pdflatex"  -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

substituting the relevant engine binary as needed.

You should also use this binary path for the following commands in the preferences:

```
"~/Library/TinyTeX/bin/universal-darwin/dvips" -o %.ps %.dvi
"~/Library/TinyTeX/bin/universal-darwin/dvipdfm" %.dvi
"~/Library/TinyTeX/bin/universal-darwin/bibtex" %.aux
"~/Library/TinyTeX/bin/universal-darwin/biber" %
"~/Library/TinyTeX/bin/universal-darwin/" %.idx
"~/Library/TinyTeX/bin/universal-darwin/" %.idx
```

Be aware that TinyTeX doesn't likely install all of these tools, so some may not work and you will need to install them yourself.

If you are mainly an R user who uses TeX from within RStudio, and just need occasional use of a TeX distribution, this route should work fine.

If you're likely to be using TeX more extensively independent of R you may want to consider installing either the full MacTeX distribution or the substantially smaller BasicTeX distribution instead of using TinyTeX.